# r array-slice of programmatically determined dimension

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, slice

Is there a way of elegantly specify a slice in a multidimensional array in R, whereby the number of dimensions is not known beforehand?

For instance, for a 5-dimensional array, slicing out the last dimension can be done using

```
fourdimslice <- fivedimarray[,,,,1]
```

but I'l like to code this for arbitrary dimensions, something like

```
slice <- arbitrarydimarray(dim=5, index=1)
```

I've not been able to understand if `do.call('[', ...)` would be an approach.  I've also tried named dimensions, but `a[fifth=1]` is not interpreted the way I would want here.

I suppose functions like `apply()` need to do similar things.

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500707/select-along-one-of-n-dimensions-in-array/14501461#14501461 answers your question.

Comment: I actually wrote some code once (when young and foolish :-) ) which looked at the number of dimensions of an array and built a string by looping on something like `foo<-'x[' ; for (i in 1:(n-1) ) foo <- paste(foo,',') ` .   V. Zoonekynd's answer is very nice indeed.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `asub`, from the `abind` package.

```
# Sample data: a 5-dimensional array
x <- array(seq_len(prod(2:6)), dim=2:6)

library(abind)
str( asub(x, 1, 5) )
# int [1:2, 1:3, 1:4, 1:5] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
str( x[,,,,1] )
# int [1:2, 1:3, 1:4, 1:5] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
all( asub(x, 1, 5) == x[,,,,1] )
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use the `abind` package, it looks like you can use a two-liner based on `slice.index`.  I don't know which is more efficient ...

```
x <- array(seq_len(prod(2:6)), dim=2:6)
library(abind)
str( y <- asub(x, 1, 5) )
```

Or:

```
z <- x[slice.index(x,5)==1]
```

This extracts the right elements but the dimensions get lost.  To restore them:

```
dim(z) <- dim(x)[-5]
```

(You could obviously wrap this in an appropriate function.)  Test:

```
all.equal(y,z)  ## TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bizarre solution to extract the first slice

```
your.array=array(runif(27),dim=c(3,3,3)) # this is to create an example of array from which you want a slice.

array(your.array[1:prod(dim(your.array)[-1])],dim(your.array)[-1])
```