# Irregular array subsetting in R

Tags: arrays, r, subset

Let's say I have the array

```
TestArray=array(1:(3*3*4),c(3,3,4))
```

In the following I will refer to `TestArray[i,,]`, `TestArray[,j,]` and `TestArray[,,k]`  as the `x=i`, `y=j` and `z=k` subsets, respectively. In this specific example, the indices `i` and `j` can go from 1 to 3 and `k` from 1 to 4.

Now, I want to subset this 3 dimensional array so that I get the `x=y` subset. The output should be

```
do.call("cbind",
        list(TestArray[1,1,,drop=FALSE],
             TestArray[2,2,,drop=FALSE],
             TestArray[3,3,,drop=FALSE]
            )
        )
```

I have (naively) thought that such an operation should be possible by

```
library(Matrix)
TestArray[as.array(Diagonal(3,TRUE)),]
```

This works in 2 dimensions

```
matrix(1:9,3,3)[as.matrix(Diagonal(3,TRUE))]
```

However, in 3 dimensions it gives an error.

I know that I could produce an index array

```
IndexArray=outer(diag(1,3,3),c(1,1,1,1),"*")
mode(IndexArray)="logical"
```

and access the elements by

```
matrix(TestArray[IndexArray],nrow=4,ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
```

But the first method would be much nicer and would need less memory as well. Do you know how I could fix `TestArray[as.array(Diagonal(3,TRUE)),]` so that it works as desired? Maybe I am just missing some syntactic sugar...

Comment: would `?slice.index` be helpful?

Comment: based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607232/r-array-slice-of-programmatically-determined-dimension/16609409#16609409 , maybe `abind::asub` is what you want instead.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions regarding `slice.index` and `asub`. I did not know these functions yet. However, they do not seem to accomplish the task I have outlined above.

Comment: BTW: I think "irregular subsetting" is more appropriate than just "subsetting" in the title. I have changed that accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if `abind::asub` will do what I (you) want.  This uses a more efficient form of matrix indexing than you have above, but I still have to coerce the results into the right shape ...

```
indmat <- cbind(1:3,as.matrix(expand.grid(1:3,1:4)))
matrix(TestArray[indmat],nrow=4,ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
```

Slightly more generally:

```
d <- dim(TestArray)[1]
d2 <- dim(TestArray)[3]
indmat <- cbind(1:d,as.matrix(expand.grid(1:d,1:d2))
matrix(TestArray[indmat],nrow=d2,ncol=d,byrow=TRUE)
```

Comment: Indeed, your indexing is more efficient. Thank you for your suggestion. As it seems, there is no way to do it as described in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Ben's answer, here a surprisingly simple modification to my original line of code that does the job.

```
matrix(TestArray[as.matrix(Diagonal(3,TRUE))],ncol=3,nrow=4,byrow=TRUE)
```

This works because `as.matrix(Diagonal(3,TRUE))` gets recycled.

Comment: You can replace `as.matrix(Diagonal(3, TRUE))` with base R code: `as.logical(diag(3))`