# R: subsetting N-dimensional arrays

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, indexing

Consider the following 3-dimensional array:

```
set.seed(123)
arr = array(sample(c(1:10)), dim=c(3,4,2))
```

which yields

```
> arr
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   10    9    8    2
[2,]    5    1    4   10
[3,]    6    7    3    5

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    6    7    3    5
[2,]    9    8    2    6
[3,]    1    4   10    9
```

I'd like to subset it like

```
arr[c(1,2), c(2,4), c(1)]
```

but the catch is that I don't know (a) which indices or (b) which dimension the indices are.

**What is the best way to access an N-dimensional array with index variables?**

```
ll = list(c(1,2), c(2,4), c(1))

arr[ll]              # doesn't work
arr[grid.expand(ll)] # doesn't work
# ..what else?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `do.call`, such as:

```
do.call(`[`, c(list(arr), ll))
```

#### or more cleanly, using a wrapper function:

```
getArr <- function(...) 
   `[`(arr, ...)

do.call(getArr, ll)

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   10    5
[2,]    7    3
```

Comment: There is one more thing: how can I assign a value to the subset?

Comment: `arr <- do.call("[<-", c(list(arr), ll, 100))`

Answer (score 1):

There is the `asub` function from the `abind` package:

```
library(abind)
asub(arr, ll)
```

which can also do a lot more, in particular extract along a subset of the dimensions (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17752012/1201032). Worth having in your toolbox.

Comment: `asub` is very nice, I didn't know about that one. Do you know if it is possible to assign values to a selection?

Comment: There is unfortunately no `asub<-` so if that's what you were really after, I'd probably recommend what I commented under ricardo's answer.

Comment: There is also afill(), as documented here: http://cran.fhcrc.org/web/packages/abind/index.html