# What is the data type by which R indexes arrays?

Tags: r, vector, indexing, subset

Suppose I have some array, *but the dimension is a priori unknown (not necessarily 3, as in the example below)*.

```
A=array(1:24, dim=c(2,3,4))
```

I also have an input vector with length equal to the dimension of this array

```
pos=c(2,1,3)
```

Based on this input vector, I want to return

```
A[1:2,1:1,1:3]
```

How can I do this automatically? In other words, what kind of data `X` do I have to pass to `A[]` so that R understands what I want.

For example, having `X` be a list does not work:

```
A[lapply(pos,function(x) 1:x)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pos = lapply(pos, seq)
do.call(`[`, c(list(A), pos))

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    7   13
[2,]    2    8   14
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am looking for something that works independently of the dimension of the array though.

Comment: edited! See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443086/r-subsetting-n-dimensional-arrays) for more.

Answer (score 0):

A function can be created to extract the desired matrix for a given array and vector.

```
A = array(1:24, dim = c(2,3,4))

pos = c(2,1,3)

array_extractor = function(array, vector) {

   result = array[1:vector[1], 1:vector[2], 1:vector[3]]
   result

}

array_extractor(A, pos)
```