# Create a variable length `alist()`

Tags: r

In this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17751172/429846), an `alist()` is proposed as an easy means of creating a list with empty elements. A use case for this would be constructing a list suitable for a call to `[` arranged via `do.call()`. For example:

```
x <- matrix(1:6, ncol = 2)
do.call(`[`, alist(x, , 2)) ## extract column 2 of x

[1] 4 5 6
```

The particular [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17750893/429846) prompting the `alist()` Answer required the setting of the empty arguments dynamically on basis of an object `shortdim`.

If one knew how many dimensions were present one could do

```
al <- alist( , , ) ## 3 arguments for a 2-d object
al[[1]] <- x
shortdim <- 1
al[[shortdim + 1]] <- 1:2 ## elements 1 & 2 of dim shortdim, plus all other dims
do.call(`[`, al) 

> do.call(`[`, al) 
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    5
> x[1:2, ]         ## equivalent too
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    5
```

A list of dynamic length can be created by `vector()`, eg

```
ll <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(dim(x)) + 1)
```

But an `alist` can't be made in that way

```
> vector(mode = "alist", length = length(dim(x)) + 1)
Error in vector(mode = "alist", length = length(dim(x)) + 1) : 
  vector: cannot make a vector of mode 'alist'.
```

Is there a way to create an `alist` of dynamic length that can be filled in later where required?

Comment: Annoyingly, `alist()` doesn't create a list of length 1, but `alist(,)` creates a list of length 2....

Comment: Related (and contains the answer) [Select along one of n dimensions in array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14502298/271616)

Comment: If either @JoshuaUlrich or @JoshO'Brien want to post the `rep(list(bquote()), n)` idiom as an Answer I am inclined to accept that as an `alist` is actually nothing of the sort, it is a `"list"`, which is what this produces too. If you don't want to I'll post it as an Answer.

Comment: @GavinSimpson -- Done. When I have more time, I'll probably further populate it with links to the various R-devel threads and SO questions that address this topic, since it's sort of interesting and mostly undocumented. (Or, anyone else, feel free to add those to my answer.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OK, I'll bite. I would probably use `list(bquote())` to construct a one element list containing the empty symbol, and `rep` that out to the desired length.

```
n <- 2
rep(list(bquote()), n)
# [[1]]
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# 
#
```

As a bonus, here is a collection of 5 ways to create/access the empty symbol that is needed as the content of each list element:

```
bquote()
# 
substitute()
# 
quote(expr= )
# 
formals(function(x) {})$x
# 
alist(,)[[1]]
#
```

Comment: If using rlang, `expr()` works too, e.g. `rep(list(expr()), n)`

Comment: `expression(,)[[1]]` works too. However I don't see why `as.symbol("")` is forbidden, since  `is.symbol(bquote())` is true and `as.character(bquote())` is `""`.

Comment: I'm guessing that "" cannot be entered into the symbol table whereas `is.symbol` is evaluating whether the argument of `quote(bquote())`  is a valid R expression. The error message for `s.symbol("")` indicates that it tests for zero-length. Trying `as.symbol(bquote())` gives no error at a console input line. Perhaps a naked language object gets a temporary name while the ambiguities are being resolved.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Ferdinand Kraft:

```
# no. of elements in the alist
n <- 5
a <- rep(alist(,)[1], n)
```

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft D'oh!!! Thanks. I was trying to do `rep(a[[1]])`, not `rep(a[1])`.

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft Actually, if you want to put that as an answer, I'll delete mine.

Comment: Nope, credit is yours. I tried something else with `pairlist`s, but it didn't work.

Comment: Or (as in the reference Joshua Ulrich points to) `rep(list(bquote()), 5)`.

Comment: I believe the canonical way of creating a missing symbol (which is what you're doing with `alist(,)[[1]]`) is `quote(expr = )`

Comment: @hadley: how do you determine whether or not it's (or anything, for that matter) is canonical?

Comment: Determine whether canonical:  does it go 'round and 'round with staggered overlays? :-)

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich because I said so :P  But more seriously, of the four or so options for creating that beast, that seems the most evocative of intent: you are quoting an empty expression.

Comment: @hadley: thanks. I agree it's most evocative of intent, but that's not quite the same as "the standard" or "the rule" (hence my confusion).

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich this is R. There are no rules!

Comment: @hadley: then you should never describe something in R as "canonical", yes? ;-)

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich there are no rules about what you get to call canonical ;)