# Look up row in array with arbitrary dimensions

Tags: r

I have a probability tables stored as arrays (outputted by bnlearn). The number of dimensions is always equal to the number of parents + 1. I always want to fetch the first the dimension and the `dimnames` of the remaining dimensions is stored in `vals` below.

Right now, I'm doing this:

```
vals = avatar[cpt$parent] # c('a','b')
eval_str = paste( "cpt$prob[,\'"
                , paste(vals, collapse="\',\'")
                , "\']", sep=""
                )
row = eval(parse(text=eval_str))
```

In the three dimensional case the code evals to this: `row=cpt$prob[,'a','b']`

Any idea on how to do this without using eval?

**Further Explanation**

I would like to subset an array by a variable with the index to subset by. For example:

```
a1 <- array(1:81, c(3,3,3,3))
```

I can subset with `a1[,2,2,3]` directly to get `67 68 69`. But if I had a variable `vals <- c(2,2,3)` and try `a1[,vals]` I get an error. Or if I try `a1[vals]` it will evaluate to the equivalent of `a1[c(2,2,3)]`.

I have also tried `do.call` since it allows for `do.call('[', ...)`. Or with `mapply(function(...) a1[...], ..)` to no avail.

I would like to have a variable of indices and subset based on those. But NOT the positions as one would normally do.

The issue appears to be in the argument structure of `'['` which is `x[i, j, ...]`. I'm looking for `j` and `...` to be supplied by an outside variable.

For now, I am using the `eval(parse(..` method to specify the spacing and comma placement. I can then turn `a1[,vals]` into `a1[,2,2,3]` but I would like to avoid that method.

Comment: Not sure what's going on here, but `eval(parse(text=x))` is (almost?) always the wrong approach. Here's guidance on asking a clearer question, that can be reproduced: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28481250/1191259 Also, your question should have a question mark, right?

Comment: This is a good question. I've tried some solutions but can't find any yet.

Comment: @PierreLafortune Care to add a reproducible example illustrating what you think is being asked?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I added an expansion. OP please chime in if you would like to clarify more/differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand it, you have an indexing vector:

```
vals <- c(2, 2, 3)
```

You want to know how to convert this into the following (without using `eval`):

```
a1[,2,2,3]
# [1] 67 68 69
```

Note that this is the same as the following:

```
"["(a1, , 2, 2, 3)
# [1] 67 68 69
```

Which can be performed with:

```
do.call("[", c(list(a1, substitute()), as.list(vals)))
# [1] 67 68 69
```

Comment: That was the missing piece `substitute()`. Great answer

Comment: Thanks! This works! `vals` needed to be appended like this: `do.call("[", append(list(dat, substitute()), vals))`

Comment: @PierreLafortune [See also here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751862/create-a-variable-length-alist) for a bit more detail on what `substitute()` is doing in the incantation above.

Comment: Or you can assign it to `vals <- c(substitute(), 2,2,3)` and then run the function with `do.call('[', c(list(a1), vals))`.

Comment: By the way OP you're welcome. Your question was about to be put on hold. Next time a good explanation can speed up the help process. : )