# Value to use as "empty index"

Tags: r

Consider the function below:

```
foo <- function (a.list, index = NULL) {
  if (is.null(index)) {
    a.list[]
  }
  else {
    a.list[index]
  }
}
```

I'd like to know if there's some value `EMPTY_INDEX` for the definition of `foo2` below:

```
foo2 <- function (a.list, index = EMPTY_INDEX) {
  a.list[index]
}
```

...that would render `foo2` equivalent to `foo`.

Comment: `index = seq_along(a.list)`?

Comment: doesn't `index = TRUE` work?

Comment: @Shape I believe that would result in something different in the corner case where `a.list` is an empty list. But I confess to being a bit in the dark as to the broader goals of the OP, so maybe that doesn't matter.

Comment: just leave no default value of index in foo2? and leave index missing if you want the whole list: `foo2 <- function (a.list, index) a.list[index]; identical(foo(1:10, NULL), foo2(1:10))`

Comment: You might get some ideas from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17750893/how-to-pass-nothing-as-an-argument-to-for-subsetting) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751862/create-a-variable-length-alist)

Comment: @rawr: AFAICT, your idea works really well; shockingly so, IMO, since I'm used to Python's conventions, whereby omitting an argument for which no default is specified in the function's definition results in an error.  Care to post your solution as an answer?