# How to subset tables based on category value using variable name?

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, subset

I try to subset a table based on one category value. Assume we want to keep only adults from the Titanic data. What I do is:

```
data("Titanic")
subset(Titanic, Age == "Adult")
```

This results in the error `object 'Age' not found`. Using same logic with dataframes works: `subset(as.data.frame(Titanic), Age == "Adult")`. But how can we subset tables directly, i.e. without transforming them to a dataframe?

**EDIT**
Here `Adult` is dimension number three. In my case I do not know which dimension it is, i.e. I would like to be able to subset by variable name as in `subset(Titanic, Age == "Adult")`. It can be any other base function, i.e. I am not stuck with `subset`. But I am looking for a base R solution.

My expected output is

```
structure(c(118, 154, 387, 670, 4, 13, 89, 3, 57, 14, 75, 192, 140, 80, 76, 20), .Dim = c(4L, 2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(Class = c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "Crew"), Sex = c("Male", "Female"), Survived = c("No", "Yes")), class = "table")
```

Comment: By the way, your expected output is wrong?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/14500707/680068

Comment: @zx8754 Corrected data structure. Link: difference is that I don't know what dimension it is in beforehand but the answers in link await dimension as argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get dimensions index by matching on *dimnames*, then use *slice.index*:

```
# user input
x = "Adult"

#get index
ix1 <- which(sapply(dimnames(Titanic), function(i) sum(i == x)) == 1)
ix2 <- which(dimnames(Titanic)[[ ix1 ]] == x)

#subset and restore dimensions
res <- Titanic[ slice.index(Titanic, ix1) == ix2 ]
dim(res) <- dim(Titanic)[ -ix1 ]

#test
all(Titanic[,,"Adult",] == res)
# [1] TRUE

# not identical as the names are missing
identical(Titanic[,,"Adult",], res)
# [1] FALSE

res
# , , 1
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]  118    4
# [2,]  154   13
# [3,]  387   89
# [4,]  670    3
# 
# , , 2
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   57  140
# [2,]   14   80
# [3,]   75   76
# [4,]  192   20
```

Comment: `slice.index` does the trick! Thank you!

Comment: @machine glad it helped, notice I am missing dimnames in the result, so not 100% same as your expected output.

Comment: I`ve noticed that, thanks. Working on will show whether this is a problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are not working on a 2 dimensional data-frame but on a 4 dimensional array.
Thus you must specify your condition in the right dimension, as follows:

```
Titanic[,,"Adult",]
```

When you display your array, you have the 4 following dimensions:
1- Class
2- Sex
3- Age
4- Survived

You can get the dimension names with "str()" or "dimnames()"

```
str(Titanic)
dimnames(Titanic)
```